# Структура базы данных для "Морского боя"

Tags: база-данных

Подскажите, какие сущности и связи лучше всего создать для проектирования базы данных игры "Морской бой"? Есть мысль создать например такие: Игрок{ID, логин, пароль}, Статистика{Игрок1, Игрок2, результат}, СостояниеИгры{Поле1, Поле2, ID_ИгрокаКоторыйХодит}. 
Что еще можно добавить? Или стоит в корне все поменять?

Answer (score 2):

- Введите 3 сущности - `{Player}, {Match}, {Move}.`
- `{Player}` принимает участие в `{Match}`.
- `{Match}` - это некоторое начальное состояние + коллекция ходов 
  (`{Move}`).
- `{Move}` по желанию может иметь обратную ссылку на `{Player}.`
- Статистика для любого игрока однозначно выводится на основании сыгранных им игр и при желании может быть закэширована (что, скорее всего, и не нужно).